# Flutter/showDialog - how to position dialog so that is under the tap position?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, I want to show a pop up dialog when I tap on a widget in my screen.

By default the pop up dialog is displayed in the centre of the screen. Can this be changed so that the pop up dialog is located close/below the widget tapped?

Answer (score 0):

Alert dialogs follow material design and generally used with some design constraint but I'm not sure if you are looking for something like pop up menu opening with respect to position.

https://pub.dev/packages/custom_pop_up_menu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dialog you could use bottom sheet or pop-up menu, but if you really want to use dialog, you could set background color to transparent, put column as a child and align items inside of that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your widget with `Align` widget

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

you can set alignment according to your need.